# Angular-chart.js custom tooltip label colors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, tooltip

I have no trouble creating a custom tooltip via multiTooltipTemplate, but it still includes the square colored box for the label.

I'd like to change the color of the boxes from fillColor to strokeColor, but I can't find anything in the documentation or code where the rest of the template is built.

Current template looks like:

```
    $scope.bar_options = {           
        multiTooltipTemplate: function(label) {
            return label.datasetLabel + ': ' + label.value;  
        }
    }
```

but this must only be part of the template because there is still a label and colored box.